# In IPython, help(raw_input) returns ' raw_input lambda prompt='' '. What is the meaning?

Tags: python, ipython

When I try to use `help()` to get some function information on `raw_input()`, what I see is something rather difficult to understand:

```
Help on function <lambda> in module IPython.kernel.zmq.ipkernel:

raw_input lambda prompt=''
```

Can anyone help to decipher this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're coding Python inside an older version of an IPython notebook, which [does not have the `raw_input()` function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing).

The reason that you see

```
raw_input lambda prompt=''
```

is because that is how Python autogenerates [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) / help messages for [lambda functions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk), because you cannot add a docstring to a lambda function.

In your version of IPython, the `IPython.kernel.zmq.ipkernel` module contains a line that makes an *empty* `raw_input()` function that looks something like

```
raw_input = lambda prompt='': None
```

In summary, to fix this, you should upgrade to the latest IPython.